# Ordering a has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2

I want to load an ActiveRecord collection with the associated collection eagerly:

```
class BodyPort < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :body_port_dimensions
  has_many :dimensions, through: :body_port_dimensions, order: 'dimensions.value'
  scope :ordered, order('name ASC')
end 
class BodyPortDimension < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :dimension
end
class Dimension < ActiveRecord::Base
end
```

eager loading the association:

```
BodyPort.includes(:dimensions).ordered
```

generates the SQL:

```
SELECT `body_ports`.* 
  FROM `body_ports` 
  ORDER BY name ASC
SELECT `body_port_dimensions`.* 
  FROM `body_port_dimensions` 
  WHERE `body_port_dimensions`.`body_port_id` IN (3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 4, 1) 
  ORDER BY dimensions.value
```

which raises the SQL exception:

```
=> ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Mysql2::Error: 
   Unknown column 'dimensions.value' in 'order clause': 
   SELECT `body_port_dimensions`.* 
     FROM `body_port_dimensions` 
     WHERE `body_port_dimensions`.`body_port_id` IN (3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 4, 1) 
     ORDER BY dimensions.value
```

How to generate an inner join SQL like instead:

```
SELECT `dimensions`.* 
  FROM `dimensions` 
  INNER JOIN `body_port_dimensions` 
    ON `dimensions`.`id` = `body_port_dimensions`.`dimension_id` 
  WHERE `body_port_dimensions`.`body_port_id` IN (3, 5, 7, 6, 2, 8, 9, 4, 1) 
  ORDER BY dimensions.value
```

Comment: This looks like a known (and fixed in rails 4) bug with the version of rails you are using: https://github.com/rails/rails/issues/8663

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following the [edsinclair patch](https://github.com/edsinclair/rails/commit/b21066871f085bc5f8c980d613986c64ec64a56f):

config/initializers/extensions.rb:

```
require "active_record_has_many_through_patch"
```

lib/active_record_has_many_through_patch.rb:

```
module ActiveRecordHasManyThroughPatch
  def self.through_options
    through_options = {}

    if options[:source_type]
      through_options[:conditions] = { reflection.foreign_type => options[:source_type] }
    else
      if options[:conditions]
        through_options[:include]    = options[:include] || options[:source]
        through_options[:conditions] = options[:conditions]
      end

      if options.has_key?(:order)
        through_options[:order] = options[:order]
        if options.has_key?(:through) && options.has_key?(:source)
          through_options[:include] = options[:source]
        end
      end
    end 

    through_options
  end
end
```